# random alphabet chooser with no repeats (python)

Tags: python, random

```
import random

alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

iterations = 1

running = True

def random_picker():

random_choice = random.choice(alphabet)

iterations =+ 1

print(random_choice)
while running == True:

    if iterations <=26:
        random_picker()
    else:
        running == False
```

I'm trying to get a different random letter through each iteration, through all 26. Each letter picked needs to update the `random_choice` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your program will continue looping until 26 letters are returned. Since you want a different letter on each iteration, it's probably easier to [`shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) the `alphabet` array and loop over it instead of trying to choose a random letter in each iteration:

```py
random.shuffle(alphabet)
```

Paul M. EDIT - Here is an example of how you might use it to achieve the desired effect:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
from random import shuffle

alphabet = list(ascii_lowercase)
shuffle(alphabet)

for char in alphabet:
    print(char)
```

Output:

```
j
m
z
w
k
y
d
f
l
c
u
b
t
s
e
p
x
g
a
r
n
h
i
q
o
v
>>>
```

Comment: how would i then stop repeat numbers from forming? The only thing I thought of was the pop() function to remove one letter from the list at a time.

Comment: @Mureinik `random.shuffle` modifies the sequence in-place, and returns `None`. @oxyzzy using `random.shuffle` is exactly what prevents repeats from occurring in the first place. Think about it: If I have a deck of cards, and shuffle it, the order of those cards will be random - but if I keep drawing cards from the top of the pile, I will never get the same card twice.

Comment: @PaulM. arg, good catch. Don't know what I was thinking...

Comment: @PaulM. How do I get it to only iterate 26 times then? or apply to a variable?

Comment: @oxyzzy I've edited Mureinik's post, because it doesn't make sense to post another answer with essentially the same solution. Take a look.